# Spring Boot: File uploading to s3 is working in local while working with ide but after build it is showing error file not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My code for the configuration of aws s3 is

```
@Data
@Configuration
public class AWSConfig {

    @Value("${aws.s3.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;
    @Value("${aws.s3.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${aws.s3.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;
    @Value("${aws.s3.region}")
    private String region;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 s3Client() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(region).build();
    }

}
```

And the file upload service file is

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class AWSUploadServiceImpl implements AWSUploadFileService {

    @Value("${aws.s3.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3 s3Client;
    @Override
    public String uploadFile(File file, String path) {
        s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, path, file));
        return "File uploaded" ;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] downloadFile(String fileName) {
        S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, fileName);
        S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
        try {
            byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            return content;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String deleteFile(String fileName) {
        s3Client.deleteObject(bucketName, fileName);
        return fileName + " removed ...";
    }

}
```

and the converter that i use to convert multipartfile to file is

```
private File convertMultipartToFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        return file;
    }
```

I try to upload file from api to s3 which is created in spring boot it is working with ide but after build it is not uploading the file?

Comment: What is the error raised? Log all the ignored errors.  There can be two possibilities - either it is raising an error while upload (you should log errors and paste them here), or it is uploading somewhere else that you are not checking (no error) - may be due to issue in setting the key of the S3 object differently in different environments. There could be differences in the configuration too